# Custom transition iOS 7

Tags: ios7, xamarin.ios

I have been struggling writing a custom transition to present a controller. What I would like to do is to have a side menu (right side), and when user makes a swipe gesture present this controller.

I already wrote a custom transitioning delegate which is presenting the controller, but I would like to dismiss it using the same kind of animation. I have tried and tried, but the controller dismisses with no animation at all, it just disappears.

This is what I have so far, I'm using xamarin IOS:

```
var container = transitionContext.ContainerView;
        var fromViewController = transitionContext.GetViewControllerForKey (UITransitionContext.FromViewControllerKey);
        var toViewController = transitionContext.GetViewControllerForKey (UITransitionContext.ToViewControllerKey);
        var endingFrame = new RectangleF (66, container.Frame.Y, container.Frame.Width, container.Frame.Height);
        var startFrame = new RectangleF (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 0, 0, container.Frame.Height);

        if (Presenting) {
            container.AddSubview (fromViewController.View);
            container.AddSubview (toViewController.View);

            toViewController.View.Frame = startFrame;

            UIView.Animate (TransitionDuration (transitionContext), () => {
                toViewController.View.Frame = endingFrame;
            }, () => {
                transitionContext.CompleteTransition (true);
            });
        } else {
            container.AddSubview (fromViewController.View);
            container.AddSubview (toViewController.View);

            UIView.Animate (TransitionDuration (transitionContext), () => {
                fromViewController.View.Frame = startFrame;
            }, () => {
                transitionContext.CompleteTransition (true);
            });
        }
```

I think the problem is with the frames, I don't know if I'm setting them correctly.

please help!!

Comment: You could easily adjust this to have the menu sliding in from the right: https://github.com/Krumelur/KSDrawerMenu (and yes, I'm the author of it).

Comment: The following tutorial might help as you could implement a UIPanScreenEdgeRecognizer to achieve this behaviour.

http://dativestudios.com/blog/2013/09/29/interactive-transitions/

Alternatively you could implement a third party framework for this there is a lot to choose from on http://www.cocoacontrols.com